# ¿Tengo problemas con las librerías de Opengl en C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

Estoy utilizando las librerías freegluth C++ para un trabajo pero me aparece el siguiente mensaje cuando ejecuto el código(Es el juego Snake) me aparecen los siguientes errores. Pido su ayuda
[image: Err]

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: [Este tutorial](https://youtu.be/HzFatL3WT6g) muestra cómo usar librerías en Visual Studio. Por cierto, sugiero que utilices un cargador como `glad` o `glew` para poder usar las últimas funciones de OpenGL.

Comment: El título de tu publicación ¿Es realmente una pregunta?